# error[E0658]: non-builtin inner attributes are unstable

Tags: substrate

I cloned fresh https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template repository (sometime ago it was working fine) I have executed:

```
cargo build --release
```

and got:

[image]

And many, many more errors while compiling. How to cope with that? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try running the commands in this script and see if that helps? https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/scripts/init.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (thanks to Dan) solved it by execution:

```
rustup update nightly
rustup update stable
// and then
cargo build --release
```

And works!